# parallel binary tree using mpi

Tags: c, parallel-processing, mpi, hpc

How are binary trees implemented in C/MPI ? And in particular, how can I gather on a processor the missing parts of the tree?

Say I want to divide a rectangle in N sub-rectangle, N being the total number of processes.

I start with a division in two sub-rectangles (along a direction and at a position that are given by a certain rule, never mind here). The left rectangle is assigned to processes [0,mid_process] and the right sub-rectangle is assigned to the other processes.

Then I do this recursively for inside these two sub-rectangles until I have, eventually, only one process left in the current sub-rectangle.

By doing this, each process is going to have a "local" part of the tree, which consists of the path, from itself to the root node.

However, later one, once the tree is built, I want each process (i.e. each final sub-rectangle) to identify which are its neighboring processes.

Assuming I have the whole tree locally, this can be done by traversing the tree, and for each leaf, look at its spatial extent and compare its boundary with the ones of the sub-rectangles we're looking the neighbors for.

This thing is I'm not sure how I send and receive the missing parts of the tree.

[image: Exemple of the decomposition and the associated tree]

The figure here shows an example of a decomposition among 11 processes, and its associated binary tree.

Let's say I'm process 2. Locally, the tree I have in memory consists in the following nodes  : [root], [0-4], [2-4], [2], where the numbers inside [] are the ranks of the processes. The neighbors of the process [2] are [0],[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QbiIT.png), [3],[4], [5], [8].

Comment: You don't really want to reconstruct the neighbour and boundary information from scratch once the tree is already built; you want to maintain that information as you update the tree, when it's comparatively easy.

Comment: MPI provides the general (graph) topology that you can attach to a communicator. With this topology in place, each process can inquiry about the ranks of its neighbours. In order to build the topology, each process must compute the nodes of the tree. See [MPI_Graph_create](http://www.mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi-11-html/node135.html).

Comment: ...but then you still need to have the entire tree information stored locally, which it sounds like the OP doesn't (yet?) have, and in some circumstances may not be feasible/desirable.  You can use [`MPI_Dist_graph_create()`](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/research/projects/mpi/www/www3/MPI_Dist_graph_create.html) to avoid having the full tree, but that still doesn't solve the problem of generating the neighbour list.

Comment: While building the tree, by keeping in memory the location of the cuts, I know what are the boundaries of the current sub-rectangle. So once the tree is built, each process already have the position of its boundary.

I'm ok with finding the neighbors while building the tree in parallel and not afterwards... I just don't see how, for instance, the process 2 is going to know that processes 8 and 5 are its neighbors ?

Comment: The same way you know what the boundaries are; by keeping track of it during the partition process.   When the original domain splits into domain 0 and 1, they each are "born" knowing their neighbours.  When 0 and 1 each split again, they update each other before the split, then create the subdomains with the correct neighbour information, etc.

Comment: Ok I think I see what you mean. But look at my picture, when the first partition is done, it splits the processes [0-4] and the processes [5-10]. At that time processes [0-4] know that their right neighbor are [5-10] and vice versa. however, later on, processes [0-4] split into [0-1] and [2-4] while processes [5-10] split into [5-7] and [8-10]. At this phase, I don't see how the processes [0-1] can know that the processes [8-10] aren't their right neighbors anymore. Do I miss something ? 
Did you implicitly assumed communications during the building phase?

Comment: I have not yet found how it is possible to find neighbours during the building phase. Could you please be more specific ?
One other way I see is to store the tree as a contiguous array on each node, and then perform a reduction so that all processes get the full tree locally, and then do what I said for finding neighbors.